# Using string to refer to arraylist

Tags: java, string, arraylist

I have a class called State and  its constructor takes a string and initialises it with another string. I want to make it so that the string in the constructor will refer to the object. The problem is what I'm passing into the constructor isn't a string its an arraylist. I want to give the arraylist a name and assign it to a variable in the main class. So that when I called the name of the arraylist it points to the arraylist or its contents. I don't want that string name to become a part of the arraylist and I don't want the contents of the arraylist to change. Is there anyway of doing this. I know c++ has pointers, maybe there is something similar.

```
class State{
   String strName;
   public State(String name){
        strName = name;
   }
}
class main{
   private TreeMap treeMap = new TreeMap();
   private String newState;
   State startState = new State();
   ArrayList setState = new ArrayList(startState);
   startState = new State(ArrayList.ToString(setState));

    newState = startState.strName;// so now newState will refer to the arraylist.
   //and i could show this by doing System.out.println(newState);

   treeMap.put(newState.strName, startState);
}
```

The put() function will associate the first parameter with the second parameter. So I want to use the string declared in the State object and associate with the same state within this treeMap.

Comment: I have problems understanding your problem, could you clarify? You want a String with value 'name' point to an arrayslist?

Comment: Sorry I've updated my question. Hopefully its a bit clearer.

Comment: Why do you need the string in the first place? Why dont you just pass the ArrayList to the Instance of the State-Object?

Comment: Sorry for making this difficult. I really should have thought about the question and put up all the code needed before asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I think I got your problem! Your treemap stores all references names -> State. So in my eyes your state should hold the reference to the arraylist, too:

```
class State{
   String name;
   List list;
   public State(String name, List list){
        this.list = list;
        this.name = name;
   }
}

class main{
   private TreeMap treeMap = new TreeMap();
   private String newState = "whatever identifier you like";
   ArrayList setState = new ArrayList();
   State startState = new State(newState, setState);

   treeMap.put(startState.name, startState); // now the State-Instance startState can be referenced via 
                                             // the String newState. The reference to the corresponding 
                                             // ArrayList is within the state object

}
```